# Web deploy to shared host?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project

Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2010's Web Deploy on shared hosts? I'm not sure how to setup the Service/Url and Site/Application parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the host will need to setup web deploy and provide you with non-admin deploy credentials.

There's a full guide on [iis.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy). The process will output a `.publishsettings` file to the desktop, which you can import into Visual Studio's publish dialog.