# Database not being created in Visual Studio Web Deploy with code first architecture on shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-first, shared-hosting, webdeploy

I'm trying to use one-click web deploy to a shared host. The website loads properly, however links that go to pages looking for the database gives

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324677/web-deploy-to-shared-host) SO answer says that:

> ...the host will need to setup web deploy and provide you
>   with non-admin deploy credentials.
>
> There's a full guide on iis.net. The process will output a
>   .publishsettings file to the desktop, which you can import into Visual
>   Studio's publish dialog.

I'm with MyASP.net, and they are running WS 2012. I just want to make sure the solution is not on my end before I send them on a wild goose chase.

My publish profile is:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://abalter-001-site1.myasp.net/</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://abalter-001-site1.myasp.net:8172/MsDeploy.axd</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>abalter-001-site1</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>ifc\abalter-001</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="">
        <ObjectGroup Name="GatorsContext" Order="1" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
            <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="Gators3.Models.GatorsContext, Gators3" Origin="Configuration" />
          </Object>
        </ObjectGroup>
        <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="2" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
            <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="Gators3.Models.ApplicationDbContext, Gators3" Origin="Configuration" />
          </Object>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String" />
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)GatorsContext-Web.config Connection String" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Web deploy settings from host:
[image]

**UPDATE**
I got it working. I wasn't actually entering the connection string for the database server on the host. This information was given to me by the host. When I put it in the web-deploy settings, all was well.

[image]

Comment: But if it's "wrong", then why would the app work fine on my local machine?

Comment: I added an image to my post that is a snip from my myasp.net control panel where they explicitly give the web deploy settings. There is nothing there about setting a different connection string. I actually thought that web deploy was supposed to make some changes to the Web.config as it uploaded it. Do you have any ideas for what I could do to create a different connection string?

Comment: Helpdesk also told me I need to change the connection string. l changed it to what is given to my by the database manager in my control panel: `"Data Source=SQL5013.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_9C4813_abalter;User Id=DB_9C4813_abalter_admin;Password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;" ` I put in my real password, of course. Now I get an error that: `The connection string 'GatorsContext' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute.` Microsoft does seem to indicate that the process should be automatic. They call it one-click.

Comment: Maybe this is what you were trying to tell me: I wasn't entering the connection string for the sql server on the host in the web deploy sql server settings! I added a picture to my post.

Comment: If you want to post an explanatory answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise, I'll answer myself.